# How to save Unity HDR renderTexture into a .exr file?

Tags: unity, rendertexture, hdr

[Purpose]:
I need to save the Unity camera view into a .exr file.

[Error]:

```cs
Remapping between formats 74 -> 73 is not supported
```

[What I've tried]:
I tried the [official solution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToEXR.html).

First, I set the `renderTexture` format as `RenderTextureFormat.DefaultHDR` to make sure that it stores HDR data.

```cs
renderTex = new RenderTexture(renderWidth, renderHeight, 16, RenderTextureFormat.DefaultHDR);
```

Then, I tried to save the `renderTexture` data into a .exr file.

```cs
Texture2D image = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.RGB9e5Float, false, true);
image.ReadPixels(new Rect(renderWidth / 2, renderHeight / 2, 2, 2), 0, 0);
image.Apply();

byte[] bytes = image.EncodeToEXR(Texture2D.EXRFlags.CompressZIP);
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/HDRs/"+tag+"reflectance.exr", bytes);
```

The error may be related to the `RenderTexture` and `Texture2D` format. I tried to change the `Texture2D` format to `TextureFormat.RGBAFloat`. The error changed:

```cs
Remapping between formats 74 -> 52 is not supported
```

It seems that the Texture2D format cannot store the HDR `RenderTexture` data, and the original data gets truncated. I've tried all the formats tagged "HDR" as listed in the [TextureFormat documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html). None of them work, some of them are unsupported... What can I do to save a HDR camera view into a .exr file?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution: have equivalent formats for both, `ARGBFloat` for the RT and `RGBAFloat` for the texture.

Thanks to @AcidArrow from [this Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-save-unity-hdr-rendertexture-into-a-exr-file.1219422/#post-7776936).